# inserting key in to another table that is created in the statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im struggling with a way to get everything i need into one SQL Statement for optimization, im using SQL Server with Visual Studio.

I have two tables

```
number
ID | number | sorted_id
0    1423     0
1    1324     0
3    8293     1

sorted_number
ID | sorted_number
0    1234
1    2389
```

Looping through an array I will re-organize the number into order so 4812 becomes 1248. I then want to put the int number into the number table and the int sorted_number into the sorted_number table, then get the ID from the sorted_number table and put it into the number table in the correct place. Doing all this without getting any duplicate values.

My current method of selecting from the table to see if the value already exists in every iteration is really bad on performance.

Any Ideas?

EDIT:

after @acfrancis response this is the code I am trying to form:

```
insert_data = db.Query("insert into sorted_number (sorted_number) values (@sorted_number)" +
                       "declare @myid int" +
                       "set @myid = scope_identity()" +
                       "insert into number (number, sorted_id) values (@number, @myid)", sorted_number , number);
```

I am receiving an error when I get to the declare section of the statement though.

Comment: why does the number have to go into the `number` table first? why not put it in `sorted_number` first, and then do a single insert into `number`?

Comment: Sorry, yeah I would insert into the sorted_number table first since i need its ID to add to the number table.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is OK but you should insert into `sorted_number` first to avoid an update to `number`. If the performance is bad you can add an index to `sorted_number.sorted_number`. Alternatively, do it all inside a single block to TSQL (a stored procedure, for example) so that you can use `scope_identity()` to retrieve the `sorted_number.ID` for the row you just inserted. That will avoid the extra select.

#### Method 1

```
insert sorted_number (sorted_number) values (1248)
declare @myid int
select @myid = id from sorted_number where sorted_number = 1248
insert number (number, sorted_id) values (4812, @myid)
```

#### Method 2

```
insert sorted_number (sorted_number) values (1248)
declare @myid int
set @myid = scope_identity()
insert number (number, sorted_id) values (4812, @myid)
```

#### Test script

```
create table number (ID int identity(1,1) primary key, number int, sorted_id int)
create table sorted_number (ID int identity(1,1) primary key, sorted_number int)
alter table number add constraint fknumber_sortednumber foreign key (sorted_id) references sorted_number(ID)

insert sorted_number (sorted_number) values (1248)
declare @myid int
select @myid = id from sorted_number where sorted_number = 1248
insert number (number, sorted_id) values (4812, @myid)

select * from number
select * from sorted_number

insert sorted_number (sorted_number) values (1248)
--declare @myid int
set @myid = scope_identity()
insert number (number, sorted_id) values (4812, @myid)

select * from number
select * from sorted_number
```

Comment: does scope_identity() always get the primary key?

Comment: Not necessarily, it returns the last identity value: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx Assuming sorted_number.ID is the PK and is defined as ``id int identity(1,1)`` or something similar, it will return the right value.

Comment: Got an error using this code:
"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 57,Token in DECLARE]"

Comment: To be honest I hadn't tested it but now I have and it works. I've updated the answer with a full test script.

Comment: I noticed (from your other question) that you are trying to implement this is SQL Server Compact. Please update the question with the correct tags. The script I suggested works in SQL Server Express 2012.